# Is it correct to run a private Docker registry like a container?

Tags: docker

I am trying to install a private Docker registry, but I m not sure how, I have installed it following this tutorial: http://www.jaas.co/2014/10/23/how-to-use-a-local-persistent-docker-registry-on-centos-6-5/
but Registry is running like a container, is that correct? or there are another ways to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done both - build from scratch and run from container.  I highly recommend you run it from a container.  It is easier to manage, and it is well [documented](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry).

Comment: Thanks Jay, I will implement my registry as a container

Answer (score 4):

Well, the instructions tell you to run it as a container, and there's [a Docker image specifically for running a registry as a container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/registry/), so I'm going to guess that it's OK.  If you don't want to run it in a container, you can [download the source code](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry) and run it directly on your local machine instead.